# Property Class having class object as a Property

Tags: c#, .net

I am having a proeprty class PropUser:

```
public class PropUser
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public PropProduct Product { get; set; }
}
```

here, 3rd property Product is object of PropProduct which is a another property class

```
 public class PropProduct
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public string  Name { get; set; }

    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in below code:

```
PropUser user = new PropUser();
    user.Product.Name = "Reebok";
```

`user.Product` is throwing Exception of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I know `user.Product` is null, so how to initialize that so that i can set `user.Product.Name="Reebok"`

Comment: Why don't you just initialize it in the constructor ?

Comment: You might Create a Constructor in PropUser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: wow i never knew there was such a thing as a "Property Class" what features does this so called "Property Class" include .

Property Class.

Answer (score 3):

If you want it initialized as soon as the class is created, create a constructor and initialize it there:

```
public class PropUser
{
    public PropUser
    {
        Product = new PropProduct();
    }

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public PropProduct Product { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Heh beat me by couple of seconds. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialise the `PropProduct` object by using the `new` operator and then assign the values.

Try This:

```
PropUser user = new PropUser();
user.Product = new PropProduct();
user.Product.Name = "Reebok";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to initialize `Product` as soon as a new `PropUser` is made, simply add a constructor initializing it in `PropUser` class.

```
public class PropUser
{ 
    //Your Properties

    public PropUser() 
    {
        Product = new PropProduct();
    }
}
```

If you want to do it "on demand" so it can be `null` sometimes, create a new `PropProduct` object before or while assigning your string :

```
PropUser user = new PropUser();
user.Product = new PropProduct {Name = "Reebok"};
```